# How can I ignore the warning "excess elements in struct initializer"

Tags: c, gcc

I want use keyword arguments in c(gcc),I follow [this link](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/keyword-arguments-in-c/)

What looks like as follow :

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <stdbool.h>    // bool - there's a bool type now

// Macro that turns the kwargs into an struct
#define my_func(...) my_func_base(\
    (struct user){.is_admin=false, __VA_ARGS__});

struct user {
    char *username;
    bool is_admin;
};

// The actual function - and yes there's single line comments too
void my_func_base(struct user u) {
    printf("Hello %s\n", u.username);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    my_func(.username="Bob", .is_admin=true);
}
```

I can call the function pretty

```
my_func(.username="Peter");
my_func(.username="Bob", .is_admin=true);
```

It will Preprocess

```
my_func(.is_admin=false, .username="Bob", .is_admin=true); ///<is_admin is overwritten
```

And when I compile the code,I get warning like:

```
(near initialization for '(anonymous)')
warning: excess elements in struct initializer
(near initialization for '(anonymous)') 
warning: initialized field overwritten
```

I real want to **overwritten** it.How can I ignore this.Use such as `#pragma GCC diagnostic` or something like.I search [GNU Warning Optings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html),`-Woverride-init`/`-Wno-override-init` is not work.

My gcc version is

```
zodiac1111@debian:src_linux$ LC_ALL=en_US arm-linux-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi
Configured with: /home/ldsh/rt9x5/linux/buildroot/buildroot/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/configure --prefix=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-sysroot=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot --with-build-time-tools=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --disable-libgomp --with-gnu-ld --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-tls --enable-shared --with-gmp=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --with-mpfr=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --enable-threads --disable-decimal-float --with-float=soft --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv5te --with-tune=arm926ej-s --with-pkgversion='Buildroot 2011.05-dirty' --with-bugurl=http://bugs.buildroot.net/ : (reconfigured) /home/ldsh/rt9x5/linux/buildroot/buildroot/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.5/configure --prefix=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-sysroot=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot --with-build-time-tools=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --disable-libgomp --with-gnu-ld --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-tls --enable-shared --with-gmp=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --with-mpfr=/opt/rt9x5/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/usr --enable-threads --disable-decimal-float --with-float=soft --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv5te --with-tune=arm926ej-s --with-pkgversion='Buildroot 2011.05-dirty' --with-bugurl=http://bugs.buildroot.net/
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.5 (Buildroot 2011.05-dirty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct option to suppress this warning is `-Wno-override-init`, e.g.:

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-override-init check.c
```

From `man gcc` (4.4.7, emphasis mine):

> `-Woverride-init` (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Warn if an initialized field without side effects is overridden when
>   using **designated initializers**.
>
> This warning is included in `-Wextra`.  To get other `-Wextra` warnings
>   without this one, use `-Wextra`
>              `-Wno-override-init`.

Note that this also affects designated initializers for arrays as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the downvote. You are right, I messed up my commandline test and thought it didn't work. Sadly I can't un-downvote. Thanks StackOverflow!

Comment: Oh wait, I'd actually changed my code on the second attempt. It doesn't work after all.

Answer (score -1):

It's a warning, so you don't have to do anything apart from closing your eyes and hoping nothing bad will happen.

It is warning because you have two initialisers for is_admin, which in general isn't what you want.

Comment: "It's a warning, so you don't have to do anything" - nope. Rather, "it's a warning, so you have to fix it".

Comment: Close your eyes and wait for something bad to happen when OS, HW, compiler, compiler version or wind direction change

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea. The OP wanted to know what to do to ignore the warning. Hence the rest of the post. He/she has to do nothing.